# Yii Framework recuperar página en CGridView

Tags: php, yii

Actualmente estoy buscando la forma de saber en que página estabas en el momento que haces click en una de las opciones de la CGriDView, y deseas volver.

Pensaba en la opción de guardar en una variable sesión los parámetros pero creo que Yii trae funciones definidas para esto.

Si alguien conoce estas funciones, me ayudaría harto.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola aqui responden tu pregunta supongo te servirá , es nativo de yii:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537875/how-to-get-page-number-in-yii

saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo iba a responderme solo, ya que logré hacerlo.